# More Moons = Brighter Nights?

Tags: planets, environment, moons, light

Now, firstly, I understand that the moon reflects a portion of sunlight onto the night's surface; So if a planet had multiple moons--say two or three, how would the additional celestial mirrors affect the night sky? Would the landscape actually be brighter, would the stars be less visible, etc?

*(I also plan for one of the moons to be similar to Saturn's moon, Titan, having an icy surface, so it'd be significantly brighter on its own.)*

Comment: *"Would the landscape actually be brighter"* ... than what? To what is the landscape compared? (Old joke: Q: What is the difference between a crocodile? A: It is longer than greener.) (For example, supposing that Titan orbited Earth at the same distance as our Moon, it would shed about 4 times as much light on Earth as the Moon does. That's technically brighter, by about 2 [f-steps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-number); but it would make almost no difference to our eyes, and would make night photography only marginally easier. A bright sunny day is hundreds of thousands of times brighter.)

Comment: Hi GN Luis. Welcome to worldbuilding! Please don't forget to take the [tour] and check out the [help]. The obvious part would be to say "yes it would be brighter, by which the resulting light pollution would reduce the ability to see stars". Yet I think there's more details that can be shed. Like if the phenomenon that moonlight cools down surfaces would change. I'll see at a later time if I can gather the necessary information, if no one else already made a good answer.

Comment: There's also a biological approach, which is that "bright" and "dim" are in the eye of the beholder, so to speak. A moonless night is dark to us, but to e.g. an owl, it's plenty to see by. An otherwise human-like species that evolved on this planet would probably think their nights were pretty dim and that ours were far too dark.

Comment: This would depend on the total angular diameter of all the moons added up and their albedo. Will there be a lot of tiny moons in high orbits or will there be few larger moons in lower orbits? Give some numbers on how many moons, sizes, orbits and surface composition and this can be answered easily.

Comment: @GN Luis Titan does have an icy surface.  But the icy surface of Titan is surronded by a dense atmosphere of  nitrogen and methane whch has opaque clouds of various substances.  So it is the albedo of Titan's atmosphere which is important, not the albedo of Titan's surface.  There are some icey moons in our solar system with high albedos.  However, it is unlikely that an icy moon would orbit around a planet close enough to its star to have temperatures suitable for liquid water using life.

Answer (score 4):

**Rings = many, many moons, much brightness.**

[image: saturn]

https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/ap061016.html

> In the Shadow of Saturn Credit: CICLOPS, JPL, ESA, NASA Explanation:
> In the shadow of Saturn, unexpected wonders appear. The robotic
> Cassini spacecraft now orbiting Saturn recently drifted in giant
> planet's shadow for about 12 hours and looked back toward the eclipsed
> Sun. Cassini saw a view unlike any other. First, the night side of
> Saturn is seen to be partly lit by light reflected from its own
> majestic ring system.

This picture is so amazing it looks fake.  Maybe I should not be surprised that a linear structure like the rings produce a linear band of light, as opposed to a point source like a moon.  Or maybe it is because the rings are closer to the surface than a moon can be, which is why they are rings.

Many moons is basically a ring and the more you have the more reflected light you can have on the ground.  Close moons would be fast moons and seen from space their reflected light might not cover a huge area - more like a spotlight zipping over the surface than giant Luna giving the lustre of midday to objects below.